# Using non-significant data for modelling/predictions

Tags: statistical-significance, modeling

**Two medical interventions A and B were compared within randomised controlled trial:**

- differences in progression free survival (PFS, i.e. how long
  patient    lived with controlled disease, from entering study    to progression) significant with p<0,001,
- differences in overall survival (OS, i.e how long patient lived, from entering study    to death) non-significant with p=0,12.

**We would like to model/predict PFS and OS beyond time of RCT. Which model should be chosen:**

1. joint modelling of OS (we don't allow differences between A and B, single OS function for two interventions), separate modelling of PFS (two different functions for A and B),
2. separate modelling of OS and PFS (four different functions for A and B, two for PFS, two for OS).

Models are build by analysing goodness-of-fit (AIC/BIC, visual inspection and comparison with external data sources) to Kaplan-Meier curves. We consider using Weibull, log-normal, Gompertz, log-logistic and Gamma distributions.

---

Please note that English is not my first language.

Comment: Assuming a large sample size generated the NS p-value, I would go for option (1).

Comment: More than 700 patients (multicenter, multinational study).